# Annoying space between nodes in a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

How to force this matrix to look like a regular table?

```
\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes={draw,minimum size=10mm},
column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=20mm}}] {
  Bob \& A \& 21\\
  Alice\& B \& 5\\
  Charlie \& F \& 2\\
};
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see what's annoying about your table.  MWE would help too.

Comment: Why not using a regular table?

Comment: @egreg well, this is a part of a larger picture; I need also to highlight some parts of this table and to reference some of these nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `matrix of nodes` aligns all nodes on their `baseline` not on their `center`. You need to add `anchor=center` to `nodes` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, 
     row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
     nodes={draw,minimum size=10mm,anchor=center},
     column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=20mm}}] {
  Bob \& A \& 21\\
  Alice\& B \& 5\\
  Charlie \& F \& 2\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ignasi! This is exactly what I was looking for.